# How do I modify the ctime of a file?

Tags: 11.04, filesystem, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change “inode change time” of a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79460/how-to-change-inode-change-time-of-a-file)

I'm attempting to modify the ctime of a file in Ubuntu 11.04.

I have tried:

```
debugfs -w -R 'set_inode_field <123456> ctime 201131100000' /dev/mapper/myserver-root
```

Where <123456> is the inode serial number of my file (entering the full path doesn't work for some reason). The command doesn't produce any output (I assume it worked?).

I then flushed the inode cache:

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

But still, no changes ... Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: In general, this is not something you should need to do.  Is there a particular reason why you want to change the `ctime` of a file?  There might be something else you can do to achieve what you want.  As far as `debugfs` goes, you may find that you need to leave the file system unmounted while modifying it.

Comment: Thanks James, this is for security research. My aim is to modify ctime on a mounted file system. If it not possible, I can accept that :-)

Comment: Well, one way to set the ctime through normal means would be to temporarily adjust the system clock before altering the file's metadata and then resetting the clock.  This is likely to leave other traces of the modification though.  It is probably possible to achieve through a kernel module too.

Comment: Thanks James. If you post these points in an answer, I can mark it.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)