# How to change "inode change time" of a file?

Tags: command-line, files, time

I tried to use

```
touch -d "2011-09-15 16:50" test.txt
```

but it just modifies the last access time and the last modified time.

```
Access: 2011-09-15 16:50:00.000000000 +0700
Modify: 2011-09-15 16:50:00.000000000 +0700 
Change: 2011-11-15 16:56:55.620124149 +0700
```

How to change the last change time?

I want to do this because my crontab uses `filectime($file)` to get the last changed time and I need to create a file of two months ago to test something.

Comment: Your crontab should almost certainly be using mtime instead of ctime, or a combination of the two.

Answer (score 5):

There is no general command to do this. However, depending on the filesystem and your administrator privileges, you can do it.

[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537291/setting-creation-or-change-timestamps) for the case of ext2/3 and possibly ext4.

Comment: Yep, this is an exact dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537291/setting-creation-or-change-timestamps . Is it possible to mark duplicate questions across stackexchange sites?